# Laravel 5 routes.php not created in Laravel 5.3 but welcome page works

Tags: laravel-5

I'm changing this question as I have first half of answer now.
I have created 2 new Laravel apps using

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel myApp
```

Both builded fine. Both of them works i.e. the welcome page shows.
But in both cases there is no routes file in `App/Http`
Creating a routes file doesn't help as it ignores it.

If I create apps with 5.2 it works:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel myApp 5.2.*
```

These have the routes file in.

How do I fix my 5.3 installation?

I'm running it on a local Windows setup.

[image: app 5.2]
[image: app 5.3]

Comment: Which command have you use for creating Laravel App?
It is composer create-project <directory> laravel/laravel

Comment: Route file is automatic created when project create. And it is located at <project_directory>/app/Html/

Comment: I've updated the question with file structure. The snips app works 100% fine. That routes file was automatically created etc.
The blog app has no routes file. The app works though i.e. the Laravel welcome page displays. But if I create a routes.php file in Http folder it ignores it.

Comment: as per question I tried both creation methods. The composer one and just the new command as per documentation. Both apps run, but both have missing routes.php

Comment: No, I can't believe that, You shoud try with composer command.
It must create Rotutes.php file same as your snips project.

Comment: So what must I do to convince you it's what I experience? I've created 4 projects now and all of them work (i.e. the home page displays). BUT the routes file is missing.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: 5.3 Only thing that changed between the working apps and today's apps is that I installed git and gulp. For the first one that didn't create routes.php i also locally installed bower and gulp for that projects. The test projects I'm creating now, I'm leaving out bower and gulp, but still no routes file.

Comment: ok. Found the issue. The snips app that works is laravel 5.2. The news ones that don't have a routes file is 5.3. I created another new app now using the version number 5.2.* and it has a routes file. How do I fix the 5.3 installation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Laravel 5.3 routes.php doesn't exist anymore. There's now 3 x route file in a folder called routes (projectroot/routes)

[image: folder]

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel  5.3, the `app/Http/routes.php` file has now **moved** to the `root routes/` directory, and it's now **split into two files**: `web.php` and `api.php`. As you can probably guess, the routes in `routes/web.php` are wrapped with the `web middleware` group and the routes in `routes/api.php` are wrapped with the `api middleware` group.

If you want to customize this or add your own separate routes files, check out `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` this file:

```
    public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    //
}

protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['api', 'auth:api'],
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}

protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}
```

You can customize your costume routes with change in this file.

Answer (score 0):

In Latest version of Laravel framework 7.5.2 routes.php is not located inside **laravel > App > Http folder**.

**App/Http/routes.php** => this file is not available (that means not located) in latest laravel Framework

instead you can find routes folder inside **laravel > routes folder**

In that there will be **web.php** file where you have to implement your new code so that code will works good

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvPft.png

So let me go to root routes/ directory
in that you can able to find web.php in that apply below code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqVyx.png

Result will be :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WMzW.png